# Unable to compare DateTime in Dynamic Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, dynamic

I'm using dynamic linq to build a query in runtime. I'm preparing the following command

```
var temp = list
    .AsQueryable()
    .Where("Date<DateTime(2014,10,22,21,05,56)")
    .Select("it");
return temp.Cast<T>().ToList();
```

The condition is not executing properly and i'm getting a wrong set of results. My filter condition is dynamic and i'll generate it only in run time. Can you help me in resolving this issue. Is there a Hour minute second comparison possible in dynamic linq?

Comment: `Date < new DateTime...` ?

Comment: @krillgar the `<` here stands for "less than"

Answer (score 2):

Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14126271/dynamic-linq-datetime-comparison-string-building-linq-to-entities)

As per the information from that link

*Note that constructor invocations are not prefixed by new. The following example creates a DateTime instance for a specfic year, month, and day using a constructor invocation:*

```
orders.Where("OrderDate >= DateTime(2007, 1, 1)");
```

Only difference I can see there is it is taking only 3 arguments. The author may not have implemented the overloaded version. Try with three parameters, instead.

[Credits](http://ecs.syr.edu/faculty/fawcett/handouts/CoreTechnologies/CSharp/samples/CSharpSamples/LinqSamples/DynamicQuery/Dynamic%20Expressions.html)

Comment: My question is I cannot pass a parameter. I need to construct the datetime on my own. When downloaded the source I can't find their method which takes 3 parameters

Answer (score 1):

When I use the [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) I can execute your predicate alright. But I would use a parameter anyway:

```
var temp = list
    .AsQueryable()
    .Where("Date < @0", new DateTime(2014,10,22,21,05,56))
    .Select("it");
return temp.Cast<T>().ToList();
```