# DynamicQueryable .Where for exactly a Date (only, no time)

Tags: linq, datetime, dynamic

I can find >=  <= etc. but not equal for a date only using System.Linq.Dynamic DynamicQueryable Where.

Does anyone have an example? Searched the whirled wild web and found nothing yet.

Example:

SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE CONVERT(date, Created) = '2016-07-08'

Answer (score 1):

Appears a slight modification of this will answer this question: [Dynamic LINQ DateTime Comparison String Building - Linq To Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14126271/dynamic-linq-datetime-comparison-string-building-linq-to-entities).

If you want orders for a specific date (no time involved):

dbContext.Orders.Where("( Created >= DateTime(2016, 07, 08) AND Created < DateTime(2016, 07, 09) )")

And per article above, if you have other columns in the WHERE clause, you'll have to build that yourself.